# ngModel breaks value attribute on material input box

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create an update function in my Angular/Material app. I've got this line here

```
<mat-form-field> <input type="text" maxlength="14" value={{user.name}} [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" matInput> </mat-form-field>
```

When I use `ngModel`, the value attribute no longer works but instead the input box remains blank. Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use one either `ngModel` or `value` binding like this -

```
<mat-form-field> <input type="text" maxlength="14" [value]='user.name'  name="name" matInput> </mat-form-field>
```

or

```
<mat-form-field> <input type="text" maxlength="14" [(ngModel)]="user.name" name="name" matInput> </mat-form-field>
```

Reason is, because when you use `[(ngModel)]` (Two way data binding) it internally set the `value` of that element as well.

**value** (One way data binding) should be used when you need to set value only of that element.

**ngModel** should be used in case of two way data binding

Answer (score 0):

Try `[(ngModel)]="user.name"`

Like this:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="14" [(ngModel)]="user.name" name="name" matInput>
```

`value={{user.name}}` should be avoided.

Comment: Oh thanks, that worked. I assumed it was used for the component.ts model, not the value.

Comment: you are welcome, please upvote and accept this answer if this helped

Comment: @AdritaSharma just asking may I know why `value` is avoided? any specific reason?

Comment: @PardeepJain For 2 way binding. I am assuming he is new to Angular and using 2 way binding using nngModel will help him :)

Comment: As you say... I just put my view, Never got any situation where value binding was useful. But of course that is correct too

Comment: in many scenario like in readonly input you can use `value` or `[ngModel]` not two way data binidng

Comment: Yes. I prefer `[ngModel]`